# No popup for links in mobile chat: Can't copy/preview/open in a new tab

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks

I long tap on links and it usually looks like this:

[image: open in new tab menu]

But in mobile chat it does something like this, where the link follows my finger and doesn't allow me to actually look at it (like many people, my fingers are non-transparent), copy it, or open it where I want it to (usually, I end up accidentally visiting it):

[image: link only shows first part of the address]

(This is a security concern! Though I am trying to be careful whose links I even long tap on in this interface.)

Can this be changed so links behave like normal, the browser default?

This happens in iOS Chrome. Safari seems to be unaffected.

Comment: I wonder if this is browser related.... what phone/browser?

Comment: Also, works for me in chrome 96 android 11